# JavaScript: How to make a variable gradually approach a target value at a given speed?

Tags: javascript

We have `x` which represents an active value, `y` represents the value we want the former to reach (may be decimal and / or negative), `z` describes how fast the former chases the later. The code is ran in an interval and each iteration is meant to get the value of `x` closer to `y` by `z` amount, based on how far ahead or behind the value is to its target. The target value can change to anything else between iterations.

For a simple example: If the current value is 0, the target value we're interpolating to is 1, while the time would probably be at a default value of 1. The result should look something like this:

```
Iteration 0: x = 0
Iteration 1: x = 0.5
Iteration 2: x = 0.75
Iteration 3: x = 0.875
Iteration 4: x = 0.9375
```

`x` never actually reaching 1 is fine since there's going to be some threshold at which to stop, eg: `if(Math.abs(y - x) < 0.125) x = y`. I primarily have an issue with the math for making x chase after y in a curved manner (slow down the closer it gets). I tried simply using `x = (x + y) / 2` which would smoothly bring the value closer as desired, but I'm not sure how it's handling negative numbers or where to plug `z` in so I can also control the speed.

Comment: `x = (x+y)/2` is the same as `x = x + (x+y)/2 - x` is the same as `x += (x+y)/2 - x` is the same as `x += (y-x)/2`, which might make more sense to you. It handles negative `y` values just fine. Plug in `z` instead of `2` to modulate the speed.

Comment: …and it's called a [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) iirc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this formula for each iteration:

```
x += (target - x) * speed;
```

```js
let x = 0;
let speed = 0.5;
let target = 1;
const THRESHOLD = 0.001;

while(Math.abs(x - target) > THRESHOLD) {
  x += (target - x) * speed;
  console.log(x);
}
```

Here's an example using this technique:

```js
let targetX = 0, targetY = 0;
let x = 0, y = 0;
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
let speed = 0.1;

document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', ({x, y}) => {
  [targetX, targetY] = [x, y];
});

const tick = () => {
  x += (targetX - x) * speed;
  y += (targetY - y) * speed;
  box.style.left = `${x}px`;
  box.style.top = `${y}px`;
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}

requestAnimationFrame(tick);
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Almost the same: This looks like it should handle negative / positive differences and speed can be customized. Thank you, will try in my code soon to confirm.

Comment: It's working almost exactly as intended! I'm getting only one problem: The movement is linear, which looks ugly for the animation I'm using it in. Can I make it be faster the further away the values are then slow down as they get closer?

Comment: It not supposed to be linear. You need to constactly calculate the `target` for each iteration. If you have two objects, the formula should look like `obj.x += (target.x - obj.x) * speed`. And also run each iteration in a timer, such as `requestAnimationFrame` or `setInterval`

Comment: Also try giving it a smaller `speed` if you're calling each iteration frequently.

Comment: The issue was on my end, I was using `Math.floor` to get rid of another problem. Your suggestion works just as intended, cheers!